Movie with ghost gunslingers that get shot but come back?
I've been trying to find this movie I saw on tv a long time ago (+10 years). I remember it took place in the mountains and there were like ghost gunslingers going after this one guy and a couple. I remember the one guys died in a truck while he was trying to fight some of the ghosts with dynamite but dropped one in the cab of the truck and it blew up. I believe the couple made it at the end and survived but I can't remember off the top of my head.

How old was it, approximately? Was it US?

By gunslingers do you mean cowboys or just ghosts with guns? And what genre is it?

I think it was an 1980's movie and it was US.

They were ghosts with guns but looked like they were from the late 1800's. I think it was more of a horror/action movie but it has been a long time.

Also if my memory is correct I think there was a special double barrel shotgun that was used to kill the ghosts permanently but I'm not 100% sure about that.

@MattLEO342 Thought it was one film but then settled on another. See what you think.

@MattLEO342 ...

Could be Ghost Riders from 1987. From IMDb:

The plot concerns an elder researcher who stumbles across the story of a mass execution 100 years before that sent a gang of crooks to their tombs with a vow to avenge themselves. At more or less the same time a group of young misfits embarks on an excursion to find the old cemetery to find the resting place of their relatives who find themselves pursued by a posse of [undead] cowboys who pick them off one by one

The group includes a couple and is led by a Vietnam vet and there's also a special shotgun that can kill the reanimated gunslingers and an exploding truck. You can see some images from it in this review.

